# How to compare two 2D Arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner trying to write a function in Java that returns `true` if two passed 2D arrays of `int` type are the same size in every dimension, and `false` otherwise. Requirements are that if both arrays are `null` you should return `true`. If one is `null` and the other is not you should return `false`.

Somehow getting an error for my code:

```
public static boolean arraySameSize(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    if (a == null && b == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (a == null || b == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (a.length == b.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].length == b[i].length) {
                return true;
            }
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Problem is "Runtime Error: null"

Comment: "*I am somehow getting an error for my code*" what kind of error? How exactly your code [doesn't work](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)? Use [edit] option to include problem description in your question.

Comment: actually there is no real 2D array in Java, it is more an array of arrays. The dimensions of the *inner* array maybe different, as you already are checking, but it is also possible that some `a[i]` or `b[i]` is `null` (you are only checking for `a` and/or `b` being `null`

Comment: Try to first study few basics of programing and arrays and loops. https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/multidimensional-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic looks almost spot-on already.  The only issue I see is in the logic handling the case where both arrays are not null *and* have the same first dimension.  You should be returning false if any index does not have matching lengths:

```
public static boolean arraySameSize(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    if (a == null && b == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (a == null || b == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        return false;
    }

    // if the code reaches this point, it means that both arrays are not
    // null AND both have the same length in the first dimension
    for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == null && b[i] == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (a[i] == null || b[i] == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (a[i].length != b[i].length) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Follow the demo link below to see some of examples of this method working correctly.

### Demo

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thanks for catching this.  I patched my answer, but I don't really like it because it is verbose.  The better thing to do would be to extract a common method.